# Loading a file from database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows

I have a program (let's call it A) that loads custom .NET assembly (let's call it B) specified in a text file. It then gets, instantiates and uses the methods located in these types.

What I need to do is have B stored in MS SQL database and when A asks to load file B then the data stored in the database corresponding to that file, are returned. I do not have access to A's source code so maybe a solution involving the OS is possible.

Another solution which fits my needs would be to be able to store raw code in database, and when assembly B is loading from a regular dll, gets that raw code, compiles it and makes it PART of assembly B. The problem I face here is that the code getting compiled is loaded as a separate assembly, which types are not read by program A.

Comment: Frankly, this seems a bit crazy. If you compile another assembly (C?), maybe you could load assembly C in a static constructor of assembly B?

Comment: Sorry I am not very experienced. By static constructor of assembly B you mean a static constructor of a static class of assembly B? I have done so with no results. It seems that program A calls something like Assembly.GetTypes() on Assembly B. If assembly B calls Assembly.Load then an assembly C is returned and apparently program A knows nothing about it.